# How to both Prepend+Append to a search-query?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi while using twitter bootstrap i have come up with this issue, i can't both prepend+append buttons to an input with the class="search-query".
I can however, do this:

```
<form class="form-search">
<div class="input-append">
<input type="text" class="span2 search-query">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</div>
<div class="input-prepend">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
<input type="text" class="span2 search-query">
</div>
</form>
```

but if i try to put both classes together it doesn't work. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks, and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code from Bootstrap's Documentation, worth a look.

```
<div class="input-prepend input-append">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">
      Search
    </button>
  </div>
  <input class="span2" type="text">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">
      Search
    </button>       
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding "search-query" to your input class and you will see what i mean.

Comment: Well yes, the search-query class has padding-right: 14px; and padding-left: 14px; so it will affect the elements around it, either remove the padding from the CSS or don't add that class.